# How to return the latest row written for the day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a FooId and a CreatedTime column. During the day, multiple rows can be inserted for the same FooId. The CreatedTime column represent the time at the moment of the inserting.

I would like a query which will return me the latest row for a given day (e.g. 2000-01-01). Is there a way to write a query which will do that with SQL Server 2005?

Below is an example of the data and the result that I am expecting. **I would like the latest data created for the day.** So the MAX(CreatedDate) won't work. Thanks!

```
FooId   Data  CreatedTime
---------------------------
1       A     2000/01/01 12:00:00
1       B     2000/01/01 12:12:00
1       C     2000/01/01 12:25:00
2       A     2000/01/01 12:00:00
2       B     2000/01/01 12:26:00
3       A     2000/01/01 12:00:00
```

Result

```
FooId   Data  CreatedTime
---------------------------
1       C     2000/01/01 12:25:00
2       B     2000/01/01 12:26:00
3       A     2000/01/01 12:00:00
```

Comment: Why all of the negative votes? I'm not sure who is doing it, but shouldn't people post a comment if they downvote?

Comment: I suspect it is the OP since everything that has MAX(createddate) is downvoted, still down't know why he deleted the original question

Comment: Next time provide DDL and DML statements so that nobody has to waste their time recreating stuff that keeps changing

Comment: You need MAX(CreatedTime) in order to solve this problem.  Or an AUTOID so that there is some sort of order to the inserted rows.  It doesn't make sense to downvote an answer that provides the desired results.

Comment: Agreed, easiest if you use Max(CreatedTime). beach's answer works, although I think mine is a little cleaner :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

of course it will work with MAX

since you didn't provide DDL and DML statements I used something I had laying around

run this

```
    CREATE TABLE #MaxVal(id INT,VALUE varchar(10),SomeDate DATETIME)
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(1,'a','2009-02-10 14:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(1,'b','2009-02-10 13:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(1,'c','2009-02-10 11:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(2,'d','2009-02-10 11:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(2,'e','2009-02-10 12:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(2,'f','2009-02-10 13:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(3,'g','2009-02-10 11:48:45.143')
    INSERT #MaxVal VALUES(3,'h','2009-02-10 14:48:45.143')




SELECT t.* FROM(
    SELECT id,MAX(SomeDate) AS MaxValue
    FROM #MaxVal
    WHERE SomeDate >='2009-02-10'
        AND SomeDate < '2009-02-11'
    GROUP BY id) x
    JOIN #MaxVal t ON x.id =t.id
    AND x.MaxValue =t.SomeDate
```

output

```
id  VALUE   SomeDate
3   h   2009-02-10 14:48:45.143
2   f   2009-02-10 13:48:45.143
1   a   2009-02-10 14:48:45.143
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing understanding of relational algebra! ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it kind of rude to delete your old post without warning because the requirements changed?  Can't you just close it so people don't wonder what happened?

In any case, **here is the updated answer:**

```
SELECT Foo.* 
FROM Foo
JOIN (
  SELECT FooId, MAX(CreatedTime) 
  FROM Foo Q
  -- Only change the dates in the next line.
  WHERE Q.CreatedTime >= '20000101' AND Q.CreatedTime < '20000102'
  GROUP BY Q.FooId, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', Q.CreatedTime), '19000101')
) Q2 (FooID, CreatedTime) ON Q2.FooID = Foo.FooID AND Q2.CreatedTime = Foo.CreatedTime
ORDER BY FooID
```

**Results**

```
FooId   Data    CreatedTime
1   C   2000-01-02 12:25:00.000
2   B   2000-01-02 12:26:00.000
3   A   2000-01-02 12:00:00.000
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (FooId int NOT NULL, Data varchar(10), CreatedTime datetime NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1, 'A', '2000-01-01 12:00:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1, 'B', '2000-01-01 12:12:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1, 'C', '2000-01-01 12:25:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (2, 'A', '2000-01-01 12:00:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (2, 'B', '2000-01-01 12:26:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (3, 'A', '2000-01-01 12:00:00')

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1, 'A', '2000-01-02 12:00:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1, 'B', '2000-01-02 12:12:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1, 'C', '2000-01-02 12:25:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (2, 'A', '2000-01-02 12:00:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (2, 'B', '2000-01-02 12:26:00')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (3, 'A', '2000-01-02 12:00:00')
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and has test code to boot - why does it have a -1?

Answer (score 1):

For all days, try this:

```
SELECT FooId, Max(CreatedTime)
FROM Foo
GROUP BY FooId, cast(CreatedTime as int)
```

for a given day, do this:

```
SELECT FooId, Max(CreatedTime)
FROM Foo
WHERE CreatedTime >= '2000-01-01' and CreatedTime < '2000-01-02'
GROUP BY FooId, cast(CreatedTime as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a computed column or another column that just stores the date. After this the query will be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work in SqlServer2005?

```
SELECT FoodId, Data, CreatedTime WHERE CreatedTime=max(CreatedTime) GROUP BY FoodId, day(CreatedTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select data 
 from fooTable 
 where CreatedTime between <beginning of day> and <end of day> 
 order by CreatedTime DESC 
 limit 1
```

Something like that, perhaps?  Not tested, off the top of my head.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support LIMIT; it uses a different wacky TOP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select f1.FooID, f1.Data, f1.CreatedTime
from Foo f1
inner join
(
    select f2.FooID, max(f2.CreatedTime) as CreatedTime
    from Foo f2
    where f2.CreatedTime >= '2000-01-01' and f2.CreatedTime < '2000-01-02'
    group by f2.FooID
) f3
on f3.FooID = f1.FooID
and f3.CreatedTime = f1.CreatedTime
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: You are missing CreatedTime in the WHERE clause (both) and a table alias in the outer WHERE. ALso, the join is off.  6 rows are returned (basically all of the data within one day).  Use the DDL from my answer to test. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: I don't have 2 Where clauses, but I did forget the second CreatedTime on the where clause.  Data does help to test...  Works now.

Comment: This is the same concept I would use, and it works... except when you have two entries with the same FooID and CreatedTime.

Answer (score 0):

**select** top 1 *
**from** foo
**where** CreatedTime between @today and @tomorrow
**order by** CreatedTime desc

(@today and @tomorrow being placeholders for the date range you want.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.FooId, x.Data, x.CreatedTime
from (select FooId,
             Data,
             CreatedTime,
             row_number() over (partition by FooId
                                order by CreatedTime desc) as rn
       from Foo
       where CreatedTime >= ...
          and CreatedTime < ...) as x
where x.rn = 1
order by FooId
```